# postgresql function: Final statement returns bigint instead of integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL ver 8.4 and have written the following custom grouping function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_group(integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
grp INTEGER,
entry_date DATE,
col1 REAL,
col2 REAL,
col3 REAL,
col4 REAL,
col5 INTEGER,
col6 INTEGER) AS
$BODY$
    SELECT ceil(rank() OVER (ORDER BY entry_date) / $1)::int as grp
          ,entry_date, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
    FROM   table_foo 
    ORDER  BY 1;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

When I try to import the function into using psql, I get the following error:

> Final statement returns bigint instead of integer

I don't understand the error message, especially since I am expecting a RECORD (well table) type back.

What is causing the error, and how do I fix this?

**[[Edit]]**

I changed grp data type to BIGINT as suggested in the comments, however I got the same error. Details:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
DETAIL:  Final statement returns integer instead of bigint at column 1.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "custom_group"
```

Comment: My guess is that `ceil()` returns a `bigint` and you defined `grp` as `int`. Try changing `grp` to `bigint` in return table definition.

Comment: @juergend: I tried that, the error still remains though. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Can you modify [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8f80f/1) example to reproduce the error? (post back the new link)

Comment: ceil() does not return bigint anyway, see the result of `\df ceil` command in psql. Wasn't the initial error message `Final statement returns bigint instead of integer` followed by a column number? If it was, please copy-paste the entire message. There's no reason to assume that the problem was at column 1.

Comment: @DanielVérité: The full message is `Final statement returns integer instead of bigint at column 1` BTW, this was AFTER I had changed grp data type to BIGINT.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: It appears that you are now getting a *different* error. You *should* get this new error because you explicitly cast column 1 to `int` and declared it to be `bigint`. My guess is that your *original* problem was `col5` or `col6` in `table_foo` is a `bigint`.

Comment: It works here (9.1.2). I guess the OP indeed has different errors.

Comment: My theory is that he error at column 1 AFTER the edit now hides the previous error. I suggest you backtrack these changes. Since you didn't post the table_foo definition I agree with @kgrittn that the most plausible suspect are col5 and col6

Comment: @kgrittn: You are correct, I had changed the db schema and forgot to modify the func to synch with the table. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Pity that the record has the grp field added. Otherwise you could have used a %rowtype, and would have avoided this datatypes-out-of-sync problem.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: Previous comment added as answer, per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit you are now getting a *different* error. You *should* get this new error because you explicitly cast column 1 to `int` and declared it to be `bigint`. My guess is that your original problem was `col5` or `col6` in `table_foo` is a `bigint`.